# Concurency between 2 where() clause with rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I have in my seed.rb something like :

```
c1 = Chapter.where(number: 1).first_or_create
a1 = Article.where(number: 1, text: 'foo bar' chapter: c1).first_or_create
a2 = Article.where(number: 2, text: 'foo bar baz', chapter: c1).first_or_create
```

and in Article class :

```
class Article

  belongs_to :chapter

  before_create do
    self.foo = true if Article.where(chapter_id: chapter_id).count == 0 

    # I tried this version too, same problem : self.foo = true if chapter.articles.count == 0
   end
end
```

the query excepted to count is :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles WHERE `articles`.`chapter_id` = 1
```

BUT, SQL log, I have :

for the first article :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles WHERE `articles`.`number` = 1 AND `articles`.`text` = "foo bar" AND `articles`.`chapter_id` = 1 AND (`articles`.`chapter_id` = 1)
```

and for the second article :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles WHERE `articles`.`number` = 2 AND `articles`.`text` = "foo bar baz" AND `articles`.`chapter_id` = 1 AND (`articles`.`chapter_id` = 1)
```

My problem is `before_create`is call before `create`, so the where in seed.rb is alwais in cache and is combinate with the where in query to count...

So the count are alwais equals to 0, so foo property alwais set at true for all articles

**How can I do an independant query?**

Comment: if it's the first article of chapter, I need to put foo at true. I will edit with an exemple of SQL, to show you the problem

Comment: The problem is that the first article (`a1`) is with `foo = false`?

Comment: no the problem is count alwais equal to 0, so a2 (and all articles) had `foo = true` !

Comment: "My problem is before_create is call before create" - and this surprises you how exactly? The thing is literally called `before_create`.

Comment: Not sure if it's completely related to your problem, but I found [this link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9894) that presents some behaviors related to scope and inheritance in callbacks. It may be a good idea your rewrite your code to not use `first_or_create`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's not this fact the problem, it's causal chain...